can send transaction
const { blockhash } = await this.solProvider.getLatestBlockhash(
      "finalized"
    );

    const test = await this.solProvider.getLatestBlockhash("finalized");

    console.log(blockhash, test.blockhash);

    const transactionMessage = new solanaWeb3.TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: signerKeyPair.publicKey,
      recentBlockhash: blockhash,
      instructions,
    }).compileToLegacyMessage();

    const transaction = new solanaWeb3.VersionedTransaction(transactionMessage);
    transaction.sign([signerKeyPair]);

    const transactioHash = await this.solProvider.sendTransaction(transaction, {
      maxRetries: 5,
    });

    return transactioHash;

I developed a script to send transactions, but recently my transactions have often not been recorded by the Solana network. Please help me check if there are any issues with the code. I'm using Chainstack's RPC.

What's the transaction ID? What does the transaction look like in Solana Explorer?
